# Phonegap app retrieves ajax and rendering error when released

Tags: android, ajax, cordova

My app runs ok when developing, I can make Ajax requests to my server.
But when I create an apk and install the app the appearence seems to be zoomed out and I can't make Ajax requests (can't log the user in with the server).

Note that I have the following code in my `config.xml`:

`<access origin="http://<ip>/*" />
 <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
 <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />`

I am generating the release with this command:

`APP_PATH/android/cordova/build --release`

What Could be the reason to this problems.

Comment: I read the solution for this on another post, but I am not sure which one hehe. Anyways here is all the info you need to know, pay special attention to point #10 of this article: https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md Also, you could read the cordova documentation on the plugin that solves this issue:
http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-whitelist/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have correct 'ip' in your 'access' tag, are you definitely calling that ip with your calls? Is it http like in your access tag or 'https'?

To debug I would change your 'access' tag to following:

```
<access origin="*"></access>
```

Set your allow intent to this:

```
<allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
<allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
```

And then run your app and see if everything works fine, if it does, the ip you used in  the access tag does not match the ip of your requests or your request was 'https' and you only allow http.

The zoomed out problem is probably a meta tag in your html, can you show what meta tags you're using?

Also to debug, consider using a remote debugger (e.g. [weinre](https://www.npmjs.com/package/weinre)) or chrome dev tools (you can connect your device and see the network calls, debug html etc.)